# Динамический View Flipper android

Tags: android, база-данных, listview, android-viewpager

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создаю приложение, где необходимо пролистывать экраны (Хочу подключить `ViewPager`). На рабочем экране стоит `ListView` с выборкой из БД. (Картинка)

Суть в том, что юзер должен пролистывать экраны почти до бесконечности, а значит новые экраны должны создаваться динамически.

Выборка из БД - трудозатратный процесс, поэтому не хотелось бы делать много экранов.

Как сделать `ViewPager` динамическим? Может есть какие-то библиотеки? Или есть у кого пример?

Comment: Не понятно причем тут ListView и ViewPager, какая структура-то?

Comment: Добавил картинку в пример

Comment: А еще непонятно, причем тут View Flipper

Answer (score 1):

Элементы адаптера `ViewPager` создаются динамически. Для назначения количества элементов, создающихся слева и справа от текущего есть метод `setOffscreenPageLimit(int numOfPagesToCreateToleft&rightFromCurrent)`

```
ViewPager viewPager= (ViewPager)findView....
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

Добавлять элементы в `ViewPager` можно через адаптер с последующим вызовом

```
viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```